emphasize neighbouring regions in matlab
I have a matrix containing label values, say identifying grains, states in made-up maps, etc. The values are in range of thousands.
The values are unique for homogenoeus region. In case of a map, there is no chance of an exclave etc, but there may be a region with just one neighbour. For example following matrix:
[a a a c c d
 a a b c c d
 a b b d d d]

I would like to visualize the map but no colormap gives reasonable results - some grain pairs have colours almost matching.
Is there algorithm to remap the values so there will be no neigbours with a same value but with much lower maximum value? The outcome that looks like some political maps where you have 4 colours that are enough to emphasize the neighbours. For example as follows -
[1 1 1 3 3 1
 1 1 2 3 3 1
 1 2 2 1 1 1]

I have tried meddling with colormap trying lines or randomized, but since the "size" of regions waries a lot it does not produce predictable results.

I think it would be good if you re-read your question with fresh eyes, and imagine what someone without your baggage could understand of this. I think your are talking about images here, but you don’t use that word anywhere. I think you have a labeled image and want to display it in some specific way. Note especially that “matrix” is a mathematical term, with a very specific meaning, and doesn’t normally contain “data”.

I think you're looking for "graph coloring", but unfortunately I see no built-in implementation in MATLAB. I did find an implementation in File Exchange, but I haven't used it and don't know how good it is.

If graph coloring is, in fact, what you're looking for, 4-coloring a planar graph isn't hard, so it would definitely be feasible to write your own. We just need clarification on your expected output.

@beaker Unfortunatelly the "data" are not in the form of a graph-representing matrix. On the other hand, naming the problem behind helps a lot.

Yes, you would have to generate the graph by finding the labels that are adjacent. Tedious, but not difficult given a labeled image.

Here is a simple way to convert a labeled image into a graph with the labels as nodes and edges between adjacent labels.

@beaker Thank you very much for the hints. It was nice to find your link to image -> graph conversion uses same idea I had had used already at the time.

Thanks to beaker's advices I was able to devise this:
inputs:

Map: Matrix containing label values. Can be double, int, char.
K: Maximum count of values for colormap(). Chosen to match K-colour algorithm below.
Distance: Diameter of neighbourhood scanning for adjacent regions.

0. ensure the label are consistent
Labels = unique(Map);
for ii = 1 : N
  Map(Map == Labels(ii)) = ii;
end

1. Matrix to Graph
Preallocate adjacency matrix. Loop over all "grains" dilate them (to overflow to their neighbours). Exclude 0 from the list (Labels outside the neighbourgood are zeroed). Fill row in adjacency matrix. Finally zero diagonal in the matrix - eliminate self-adjacency.
Graph = false(N);

for ii = 1:N
  Grain = imdilate(Map == ii, strel('disk', Distance));
  Neighbours = unique(Map .* Grain);
  Neighbours = Neighbours(Neighbours ~= 0);
  Graph(Neighbours, ii) = true;
  Graph(ii, Neighbours) = true;
end

Graph = Graph & ~eye(size(Graph))

2. Use modified Kempe's K-colour algorithm
2.1. Preallocate working variables
Preallocate Stack variable to keep trace of nodes removed form the graph, Pruned to keep 'pruned' graph, Pool to keep 'active' nodes and Codes to store 'Colour codes'.
N = numel(Labels);
Stack = nan(N, 1);
Pruned = Graph;
Pool = 1 : N;
Codes = nan(1, N);

2.2. Dismantle the graph
Find node with least neighbours, put its index on stack and delete it from adjacency matrix (prune it). Repeat with pruned adjacency matrix until last node is on the stack and adjacency matrix is empty.
for ii = 1 : N
  Degrees = sum(Pruned);
  [~, idmin] = find(Degrees == min(Degrees), 1);
  [~, Pruned] = pop(Pruned, idmin);
  Stack(ii) = Pool(idmin);
  [~, Pool] = pop(Pool, idmin);
end

2.3. ('Reassenble' the graph) and assign codes
for ii = N : -1 : 1 % Start with last node in the stack
  % Read colour codes of neighbouring nodes. `NaN` returned for nodes still on stack* 
  NgbCodes = Codes(Graph(Stack(ii), :));
  % Check count of codes used in neighbouring nodes.
  if sum(~isnan(unique(K))) < Ncolours
    % If lower than number of codes, find the unused codes
    ColorPool = setdiff(CodeList, NgbCodes);
    % Assign the first unused code to the node
    Codes(Stack(ii)) = ColorPool(1);
  else
    % If all codes are used, leave unassigned (let user increase K and try again)
  end
end

3. Apply the codes to the matrix
Map = Codes(Map);

Nested functions
Both functions pop rc-th element, or column, respectively, from matrix or vector.
function [CLMN, B] = prune(A, rc)
  CLMN = A(:, rc);
  B = A([1 : rc - 1, rc + 1 : end], :);
  B = B(:, [1 : rc - 1, rc + 1 : end]);
end

function [Val, B] = pop(A, rc)
  Val = A(rc);
  B = A([1 : rc - 1, rc + 1 : end]);
end


Modifications in the algorithm described in linked presentation, page 9:

I do not look for (any) node with Degree D < K, I look for node with lowest degree (no matter how related to K). If D < K is valid for at least one node, it is found. If such node does not exist (easy for K=3) the branches do not differ significantly.
I don't use recursive call, stack and other variable sizes are determined in the beginning and they only shrink.
Condition  for neighbouring colour codes assigned count NC < K is automatically true for D < K - no need for such check then.

